# .net MVC4 path file .js in the nested web pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with mvc4 application.
I have created a masterpage with "bundleconfig" for css and js file.
so far so good ... everything works, such as "localhost1234:/Admin/Index" I see everything correctly.
The problem is when I go to the page "localhost1234:/Admin/Edit/2" (2 is user id por update) here does not find references in the file main.js

The file main.js is this:

`

```
head.js("../assets/js/skin-select/jquery.cookie.js");
head.js("../assets/js/skin-select/skin-select.js");
head.js("../assets/js/clock/date.js");
```

`
In the error console of the browser says that not found the reference:

```
404 Not Found - localhost:1234/Admin/assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"
jquery.cookie.js
404 Not Found - localhost:1234/Admin/assets/js/bootstrap.js"
```

Why he put the name of the view (Admin) front the path in the main.js file ???
Can you help me?

Comment: Because your controller name is Admin.  Try `~/assets/....cookie.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Url.Content` helper to generate the right path from the relative path like this:

```
head.js('@Url.Content("~/assets/js/skin-select/jquery.cookie.js")');
```

Currently it is trying to find in the **Admin** folder **assets--> js-->jquery.cookie.js**.

After using `Url.Content()` it will first get the **RootDirectory** and the address will be like : `http://localhost/assests/js/skin-select/jquery.cookie.js`

Comment: If I put your solution inside the file .js I have the same error from console:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:49460/Admin/@Url.Content(%22assets/js/skin-select/jquery.cookie.js%22)"

Thank you

Comment: try putting Url.Content with your main.js

Comment: If I put in the master page:<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("~/assets/js/main.js");></script> I have 404 error not found main.js

Comment: assests folder is is root directory of project?

Comment: it is one of the main folders

Comment: All js works but when arrive in this page: 'localhost1234:/Admin/Edit/2' the js path dont work put the '/Admin' after correct path: 404 Not Found - localhost:1234/Admin/assets/js/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Actually the relative path ia not right due to which absolute path is not same when url changes